# pdflatex out of memory using pgfplotstableread and csv

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, pgf

I'm unable to read my csv file using pgfplotstableread.

I already increased the memory size alot (consuming now > 1GB RAM), but still I'm getting this error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=378000000]`

My other csv files are working fine, here is the code and the content (the complete file really just has 11 lines).

myfile.csv:

```
xAxis,yAxis
"2017-05-17T10:45:30Z",5379056
"2017-05-17T10:45:35Z",7197586
"2017-05-17T10:45:40Z",11801386
"2017-05-17T10:45:45Z",12846031
"2017-05-17T10:45:50Z",12673549
"2017-05-17T10:45:55Z",12524474
"2017-05-17T10:46:00Z",14060701
"2017-05-17T10:46:05Z",15437277
"2017-05-17T10:46:10Z",14413577
```

Usage:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{myfile.csv}\somevalues
```

Any ideas on this? I can't imagine what's wrong.

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce the problem with the information you have given.  [This example document](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/38129f02769b9c5ec97e6366a5dfdc64) works perfectly fine.  I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: You are using filecontents. Thats working fine in my document, too. Did you try it exactly as I described? Loading the the external file?

Comment: If you are running out of memory use `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`.